# How can I interface with a C callback definition containing va_args in Delphi?

Tags: c, delphi, dll, variadic-functions

A C library that I would like to integrate in Delphi contains the following debug log call back function definition:

```
typedef void (*libfoo_log_cb)(void *data, int level, const char *fmt, va_list args);
```

The signature of my callback function in Delphi looks like this:

```
procedure LibFooLog( data: Pointer; level: Integer; fmt: PAnsiChar; args: Pointer ); cdecl;
```

When the callback function is triggered by the C library the "fmt" string obviously contains a lot of printf specifiers like "%s" etc. How can I assemble the string from "fmt" and the va-list "args" in Delphi? Maybe I can use the MSVCRT run-time of Windows to do the formatting but how would I map the arguments to it?

Comment: Trying this again. I think you may find `vaargs` directive useful.

Comment: But if I understand correctly the `varargs` directive would only help if the callback would use an ellipsis like `const char *fmt, ...);` instead of `const char *fmt, va_list args);`. Anyway I can only call into a C varargs function in Delphi, but I dont think it is possible to create a varargs function in Delphi which can be called from C.

Comment: Sorry. I completely misunderstood. I was going to ask what is stopping you from providing a `varargs` directive function, then in C code building the `va_list` to invoke your original `libfoo_log_cb` callback? Then I realized you're actually trying to invoke a Delphi callback from C code. I suppose perhaps you could always do a `vsnprintf` solutionon the C side, then just pass the single log text message to delphi. function expecting only that and nothing more. Iow, C does the format, then sends a string to Delphi.

Comment: Luckily the C library in an open-source project, so yes if anything fails I will go the route to patch the source code of the external library and regenerate the DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility to let the Windows system's C runtime library do the string formatting. This should work if (and only if) the C library that accepts the callback also is linked to the same C runtime library.

Example Code:

```
function vsnprintf( buffer: PAnsiChar; count: LongWord; format: PAnsiChar; argptr: Pointer ): Integer; cdecl; external 'msvcrt.dll';

procedure LibFooLog( data: Pointer; level: Integer; fmt: PAinsiChar; args: Pointer ); cdecl;
var
   Buffer: array[0..4096] of AnsiChar;
   Count: Integer;
begin
   Count := vsnprintf(@Buffer[0], SizeOf(Buffer), fmt, args);
   if Count > 0 then
   begin
      // cast the output to string with AnsiString(Buffer) and do something with it
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

C has a struct called va_list. Args should point to a instance. I don't know much about delphi, but you can write a function in C, that returns a va_list and use it as the *args* argument. You may need to allocate it instead of using the normal stack allocation of a va_list.

Comment: Is the `va_list` struct standardized? Would I need to use the same C compiler + headers for passing the format string and va_list arguments to some vprintf-style function?

Comment: No I don't think so... no posix, ISO doesn't describe the struct... Could Array of const work instead of pointer?

Comment: "*Is the va_list struct standardized?*" - no. It is compiler-dependent.